# OpenShift Master not starting - assetConfig.servingInfo invalid value “”

Tags: redhat, kubernetes, rhel7, openshift-origin

I've installed OpenShift Enterprise 3.2 on a RHEL 7 system using the official advanced documentation [using this template](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#single-master). My installation currently consists of 2 machines: a master and a node.
I ran the ansible playbook with the following command:

```
ansible-playbook /usr/share/ansible/openshift-ansible/playbooks/byo/config.yml
```

It finishes successfully. However, when I try to open the OpenShift console in the browser the page is unable to open, which made me check the service status. It repeatedly fails with the log attached.
What makes me wonder is if the `invalid value`-warnings at the beginning of the log lead to the errors?

In order to use lets encrypt ssl certificates, I added the following lines to /etc/ansible/hosts:

```
openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname=myhost
openshift_master_overwrite_named_certificates=true
openshift_master_named_certificates=[{"certfile": "/etc/letsencrypt/archive/myhost/fullchain.pem", "keyfile": "/etc/letsencrypt/archive/myhost/privkey.pem", "names": ["myhost"]}]
```

This is what I found in the master service's journal:

```
os-master systemd[1]: Starting Atomic OpenShift Master...
W0128 10:52:59.306231   19245 start_master.go:271] assetConfig.loggingPublicURL: Invalid value: "": required to view aggregated container logs in the console
W0128 10:52:59.306308   19245 start_master.go:271] assetConfig.metricsPublicURL: Invalid value: "": required to view cluster metrics in the console
W0128 10:52:59.306334   19245 start_master.go:271] assetConfig.servingInfo: Invalid value: "\u003cnot displayed\u003e": changes to assetConfig certificate configuration are not used when colocated with master API
E0128 10:52:59.811565   19245 cacher.go:220] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:163: Failed to list *api.ClusterPolicy: error #0: dial tcp 192.168.0.235:4001: connection refused
E0128 10:52:59.811592   19245 cacher.go:220] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:163: Failed to list *api.ClusterPolicyBinding: error #0: dial tcp 192.168.0.235:4001: connection refused
E0128 10:52:59.811647   19245 cacher.go:220] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:163: Failed to list *api.PolicyBinding: error #0: dial tcp 192.168.0.235:4001: connection refused
E0128 10:52:59.811653   19245 cacher.go:220] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:163: Failed to list *api.Policy: error #0: dial tcp 192.168.0.235:4001: connection refused
E0128 10:52:59.811685   19245 cacher.go:220] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:163: Failed to list *api.Group: error #0: dial tcp 192.168.0.235:4001: connection refused
E0128 10:52:59.812919   19245 cacher.go:220] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:163: Failed to list *api.OAuthAccessToken: error #0: dial tcp 192.168.0.235:4001: connection refused
E0128 10:52:59.813097   19245 cacher.go:220] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:163: Failed to list *api.User: error #0: dial tcp 192.168.0.235:4001: connection refused
I0128 10:53:00.071073   19245 plugins.go:71] No cloud provider specified.
I0128 10:53:00.189257   19245 genericapiserver.go:82] Adding storage destination for group
I0128 10:53:00.189305   19245 genericapiserver.go:82] Adding storage destination for group extensions
I0128 10:53:00.189325   19245 start_master.go:384] Starting master on 0.0.0.0:8443 (v3.2.1.34-20-g6367d5d)
I0128 10:53:00.189331   19245 start_master.go:385] Public master address is https://cluster.test-env.local:8443
I0128 10:53:00.189350   19245 start_master.go:389] Using images from "openshift3/ose-<component>:v3.2.1.34"
I0128 10:53:00.309754   19245 server.go:64] etcd: peerTLS: cert = /etc/origin/master/etcd.server.crt, key = /etc/origin/master/etcd.server.key, ca = /etc/origin/master/ca-bundle.crt, trusted-ca = , client-cert-auth = false
I0128 10:53:00.435788   19245 server.go:75] etcd: listening for peers on https://0.0.0.0:7001
I0128 10:53:00.435831   19245 server.go:86] etcd: clientTLS: cert = /etc/origin/master/etcd.server.crt, key = /etc/origin/master/etcd.server.key, ca = /etc/origin/master/ca-bundle.crt, trusted-ca = , client-cert-auth = false
I0128 10:53:00.559343   19245 server.go:100] etcd: listening for client requests on https://0.0.0.0:4001
I0128 10:53:00.691274   19245 run.go:61] Started etcd at os-master:4001
I0128 10:53:00.850210   19245 run_components.go:204] Using default project node label selector:
I0128 10:53:00.977996   19245 master.go:79] Using the lease endpoint reconciler
W0128 10:53:01.292447   19245 lease_endpoint_reconciler.go:174] Resetting endpoints for master service "kubernetes" to [192.168.0.235]
I0128 10:53:01.584964   19245 master.go:264] Started Kubernetes API at 0.0.0.0:8443/api/v1
I0128 10:53:01.584996   19245 master.go:264] Started Kubernetes API Extensions at 0.0.0.0:8443/apis/extensions/v1beta1
I0128 10:53:01.585001   19245 master.go:264] Started Origin API at 0.0.0.0:8443/oapi/v1
I0128 10:53:01.585005   19245 master.go:264] Started OAuth2 API at 0.0.0.0:8443/oauth
I0128 10:53:01.585009   19245 master.go:264] Started Web Console 0.0.0.0:8443/console/
I0128 10:53:01.585013   19245 master.go:264] Started Swagger Schema API at 0.0.0.0:8443/swaggerapi/
I0128 10:53:01.905160   19245 ensure.go:231] Ignoring bootstrap policy file because cluster policy found
I0128 10:53:02.109520   19245 ensure.go:86] Added build-controller service accounts to the system:build-controller cluster role: <nil>
I0128 10:53:02.236048   19245 ensure.go:86] Added daemonset-controller service accounts to the system:daemonset-controller cluster role: <nil>
I0128 10:53:02.348228   19245 ensure.go:86] Added deployment-controller service accounts to the system:deployment-controller cluster role: <nil>
I0128 10:53:02.450625   19245 ensure.go:86] Added gc-controller service accounts to the system:gc-controller cluster role: <nil>
I0128 10:53:02.555825   19245 ensure.go:86] Added hpa-controller service accounts to the system:hpa-controller cluster role: <nil>
I0128 10:53:02.651823   19245 ensure.go:86] Added job-controller service accounts to the system:job-controller cluster role: <nil>
I0128 10:53:02.754298   19245 ensure.go:86] Added namespace-controller service accounts to the system:namespace-controller cluster role: <nil>
I0128 10:53:02.852278   19245 ensure.go:86] Added pv-binder-controller service accounts to the system:pv-binder-controller cluster role: <nil>
I0128 10:53:02.956611   19245 ensure.go:86] Added pv-provisioner-controller service accounts to the system:pv-provisioner-controller cluster role: <nil>
I0128 10:53:03.058727   19245 ensure.go:86] Added pv-recycler-controller service accounts to the system:pv-recycler-controller cluster role: <nil>
I0128 10:53:03.154841   19245 ensure.go:86] Added replication-controller service accounts to the system:replication-controller cluster role: <nil>
W0128 10:53:03.156189   19245 run_components.go:179] Binding DNS on port 8053 instead of 53 (you may need to run as root and update your config), using 0.0.0.0:8053 which will not resolve from all locations
I0128 10:53:03.357280   19245 run_components.go:199] DNS listening at 0.0.0.0:8053
os-master systemd[1]: Started Atomic OpenShift Master.
I0128 10:53:03.357370   19245 start_master.go:528] Controllers starting (*)
I0128 10:53:03.546822   19245 nodecontroller.go:143] Sending events to api server.
I0128 10:53:03.547298   19245 factory.go:155] Creating scheduler from configuration: {{ } [{PodFitsHostPorts <nil>} {PodFitsResources <nil>} {NoDiskConflict <nil>} {NoVolumeZoneConflict <nil>} {MatchNodeSelector <nil>} {MaxEBSVolumeCount <nil>} {MaxGCEPDVolumeCount <nil>} {Region 0xc20d4d5f40}] [{LeastRequestedPriority 1 <nil>} {BalancedResourceAllocation 1 <nil>} {SelectorSpreadPriority 1 <nil>} {NodeAffinityPriority 1 <nil>} {Zone 2 0xc20ccacbf0}] []}
I0128 10:53:03.547356   19245 factory.go:164] Registering predicate: PodFitsHostPorts
I0128 10:53:03.547371   19245 plugins.go:122] Predicate type PodFitsHostPorts already registered, reusing.
I0128 10:53:03.547394   19245 factory.go:164] Registering predicate: PodFitsResources
I0128 10:53:03.547402   19245 plugins.go:122] Predicate type PodFitsResources already registered, reusing.
I0128 10:53:03.547416   19245 factory.go:164] Registering predicate: NoDiskConflict
I0128 10:53:03.547423   19245 plugins.go:122] Predicate type NoDiskConflict already registered, reusing.
I0128 10:53:03.547436   19245 factory.go:164] Registering predicate: NoVolumeZoneConflict
I0128 10:53:03.547444   19245 plugins.go:122] Predicate type NoVolumeZoneConflict already registered, reusing.
I0128 10:53:03.547461   19245 factory.go:164] Registering predicate: MatchNodeSelector
I0128 10:53:03.547468   19245 plugins.go:122] Predicate type MatchNodeSelector already registered, reusing.
I0128 10:53:03.547483   19245 factory.go:164] Registering predicate: MaxEBSVolumeCount
I0128 10:53:03.547491   19245 plugins.go:122] Predicate type MaxEBSVolumeCount already registered, reusing.
I0128 10:53:03.547506   19245 factory.go:164] Registering predicate: MaxGCEPDVolumeCount
I0128 10:53:03.547514   19245 plugins.go:122] Predicate type MaxGCEPDVolumeCount already registered, reusing.
I0128 10:53:03.547529   19245 factory.go:164] Registering predicate: Region
I0128 10:53:03.547544   19245 factory.go:170] Registering priority: LeastRequestedPriority
I0128 10:53:03.547553   19245 plugins.go:191] Priority type LeastRequestedPriority already registered, reusing.
I0128 10:53:03.547574   19245 factory.go:170] Registering priority: BalancedResourceAllocation
I0128 10:53:03.547582   19245 plugins.go:191] Priority type BalancedResourceAllocation already registered, reusing.
I0128 10:53:03.547601   19245 factory.go:170] Registering priority: SelectorSpreadPriority
I0128 10:53:03.547610   19245 plugins.go:191] Priority type SelectorSpreadPriority already registered, reusing.
I0128 10:53:03.547629   19245 factory.go:170] Registering priority: NodeAffinityPriority
I0128 10:53:03.547638   19245 plugins.go:191] Priority type NodeAffinityPriority already registered, reusing.
I0128 10:53:03.547655   19245 factory.go:170] Registering priority: Zone
I0128 10:53:03.547669   19245 factory.go:190] creating scheduler with fit predicates 'map[MaxGCEPDVolumeCount:{} Region:{} PodFitsHostPorts:{} PodFitsResources:{} NoDiskConflict:{} NoVolumeZoneConflict:{} MatchNodeSelector:{} MaxEBSVolumeCount:{}]' and priority functions 'map[NodeAffinityPriority:{} Zone:{} LeastRequestedPriority:{} BalancedResourceAllocation:{} SelectorSpreadPriority:{}]
I0128 10:53:03.548922   19245 replication_controller.go:208] Starting RC Manager
I0128 10:53:03.549637   19245 horizontal.go:120] Starting HPA Controller
I0128 10:53:03.549977   19245 controller.go:211] Starting Daemon Sets controller manager
I0128 10:53:03.553095   19245 nodecontroller.go:416] NodeController observed a new Node: api.Node{TypeMeta:unversioned.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:api.ObjectMeta{Name:"node01.test-env.local", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"/api/v1/nodes/node01.test-env.local", UID:"67be84ed-180c-11e9-83d6-ac1f6bb2846e", ResourceVersion:"279250", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:63683074517, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x59af580)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*unversioned.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string{"kubernetes.io/hostname":"node01.test-env.local", "region":"primary", "zone":"worker"}, Annotations:map[string]string(nil)}, Spec:api.NodeSpec{PodCIDR:"", ExternalID:"node01.test-env.local", ProviderID:"", Unschedulable:false}, Status:api.NodeStatus{Capacity:api.ResourceList{"cpu":resource.Quantity{Amount:20.000, Format:"DecimalSI"}, "memory":resource.Quantity{Amount:33284198400.000, Format:"BinarySI"}, "pods":resource.Quantity{Amount:110.000, Format:"DecimalSI"}}, Allocatable:api.ResourceList{"memory":resource.Quantity{Amount:33284198400.000, Format:"BinarySI"}, "pods":resource.Quantity{Amount:110.000, Format:"DecimalSI"}, "cpu":resource.Quantity{Amount:20.000, Format:"DecimalSI"}}, Phase:"", Conditions:[]api.NodeCondition{api.NodeCondition{Type:"OutOfDisk", Status:"False", LastHeartbeatTime:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:63683931884, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x59af580)}}, LastTransitionTime:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:63683074517, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x59af580)}}, Reason:"KubeletHasSufficientDisk", Message:"kubelet has sufficient disk space available"}, api.NodeCondition{Type:"Ready", Status:"True", LastHeartbeatTime:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:63683931884, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x59af580)}}, LastTransitionTime:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:63683844451, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x59af580)}}, Reason:"KubeletReady", Message:"kubelet is posting ready status"}}, Addresses:[]api.NodeAddress{api.NodeAddress{Type:"LegacyHostIP", Address:"192.168.0.236"}, api.NodeAddress{Type:"InternalIP", Address:"192.168.0.236"}}, DaemonEndpoints:api.NodeDaemonEndpoints{KubeletEndpoint:api.DaemonEndpoint{Port:10250}}, NodeInfo:api.NodeSystemInfo{MachineID:"13c8c5e54f714391b2a53a5c94bcc5bf", SystemUUID:"00000000-0000-0000-0000-AC1F6BB20CA8", BootID:"308d0709-f19f-4086-a2e1-0eff144a87bf", KernelVersion:"3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64", OSImage:"Unknown", ContainerRuntimeVersion:"docker://1.10.3", KubeletVersion:"v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5", KubeProxyVersion:"v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5"}, Images:[]api.ContainerImage{api.ContainerImage{Names:[]string{"registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-deployer:v3.2.1.34"}, SizeBytes:484648699}, api.ContainerImage{Names:[]string{"registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-pod:v3.2.1.34"}, SizeBytes:216220653}}}}
I0128 10:53:03.553324   19245 nodecontroller.go:604] Recording Registered Node node01.test-env.local in NodeController event message for node node01.test-env.local
I0128 10:53:03.553350   19245 nodecontroller.go:416] NodeController observed a new Node: api.Node{TypeMeta:unversioned.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:api.ObjectMeta{Name:"os-master", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"/api/v1/nodes/os-master", UID:"3aaf8c61-1805-11e9-b470-ac1f6bb2846e", ResourceVersion:"279249", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:63683071434, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x59af580)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*unversioned.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string{"region":"infra", "zone":"default", "kubernetes.io/hostname":"os-master"}, Annotations:map[string]string(nil)}, Spec:api.NodeSpec{PodCIDR:"", ExternalID:"os-master", ProviderID:"", Unschedulable:false}, Status:api.NodeStatus{Capacity:api.ResourceList{"cpu":resource.Quantity{Amount:20.000, Format:"DecimalSI"}, "memory":resource.Quantity{Amount:33284198400.000, Format:"BinarySI"}, "pods":resource.Quantity{Amount:110.000, Format:"DecimalSI"}}, Allocatable:api.ResourceList{"cpu":resource.Quantity{Amount:20.000, Format:"DecimalSI"}, "memory":resource.Quantity{Amount:33284198400.000, Format:"BinarySI"}, "pods":resource.Quantity{Amount:110.000, Format:"DecimalSI"}}, Phase:"", Conditions:[]api.NodeCondition{api.NodeCondition{Type:"OutOfDisk", Status:"False", LastHeartbeatTime:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:63683931882, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x59af580)}}, LastTransitionTime:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:63683071434, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x59af580)}}, Reason:"KubeletHasSufficientDisk", Message:"kubelet has sufficient disk space available"}, api.NodeCondition{Type:"Ready", Status:"True", LastHeartbeatTime:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:63683931882, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x59af580)}}, LastTransitionTime:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:63683920546, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x59af580)}}, Reason:"KubeletReady", Message:"kubelet is posting ready status"}}, Addresses:[]api.NodeAddress{api.NodeAddress{Type:"LegacyHostIP", Address:"192.168.0.235"}, api.NodeAddress{Type:"InternalIP", Address:"192.168.0.235"}}, DaemonEndpoints:api.NodeDaemonEndpoints{KubeletEndpoint:api.DaemonEndpoint{Port:10250}}, NodeInfo:api.NodeSystemInfo{MachineID:"c9cd124ae34b47e4ab2b47251d647876", SystemUUID:"00000000-0000-0000-0000-AC1F6BB2846E", BootID:"66b7397b-70d2-4089-848a-83f1c35772de", KernelVersion:"3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64", OSImage:"Unknown", ContainerRuntimeVersion:"docker://1.10.3", KubeletVersion:"v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5", KubeProxyVersion:"v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5"}, Images:[]api.ContainerImage{api.ContainerImage{Names:[]string{"registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-deployer:v3.2.1.34"}, SizeBytes:484648699}, api.ContainerImage{Names:[]string{"registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-docker-registry:v3.2.1.34"}, SizeBytes:531472384}, api.ContainerImage{Names:[]string{"registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-pod:v3.2.1.34"}, SizeBytes:216220653}, api.ContainerImage{Names:[]string{"registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-haproxy-router:v3.2.1.34"}, SizeBytes:488011184}}}}
I0128 10:53:03.553519   19245 nodecontroller.go:604] Recording Registered Node os-master in NodeController event message for node os-master
W0128 10:53:03.553540   19245 nodecontroller.go:671] Missing timestamp for Node node01.test-env.local. Assuming now as a timestamp.
W0128 10:53:03.553557   19245 nodecontroller.go:671] Missing timestamp for Node os-master. Assuming now as a timestamp.
I0128 10:53:03.553742   19245 event.go:211] Event(api.ObjectReference{Kind:"Node", Namespace:"", Name:"node01.test-env.local", UID:"node01.test-env.local", APIVersion:"", ResourceVersion:"", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RegisteredNode' Node node01.test-env.local event: Registered Node node01.test-env.local in NodeController
I0128 10:53:03.553815   19245 event.go:211] Event(api.ObjectReference{Kind:"Node", Namespace:"", Name:"os-master", UID:"os-master", APIVersion:"", ResourceVersion:"", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RegisteredNode' Node os-master event: Registered Node os-master in NodeController
F0128 10:53:03.654255   19245 master.go:127] Failed to get supported resources from server: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
I0128 10:53:03.745620   19245 endpoints_controller.go:283] Waiting for pods controller to sync, requeuing rc mih-testing/jenkins123
I0128 10:53:03.745663   19245 endpoints_controller.go:283] Waiting for pods controller to sync, requeuing rc default/docker-registry
os-master systemd[1]: atomic-openshift-master.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
os-master systemd[1]: Unit atomic-openshift-master.service entered failed state.
os-master systemd[1]: atomic-openshift-master.service failed.
```

Comment: It looks like some certificate didn't get copied in somewhere. I would suggest first getting the cluster working with its own generated self-signed certs, and then switching to your Let's Encrypt certs.

Comment: I already suspected the certificates as I had the server running without lets encrypt before. Could you please tell me which line tells you about missing certificates? I'm new to openshift and didn't find an indicator about this in the log

Comment: The embedded etcd did not start on port 4001. The only useful message near those log entries references certificates: "changes to assetConfig certificate configuration are not used when colocated with master API"